# Why resize function is not working on iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

im triying to figure out why my resize function is not working. I tried to change values of style.height but seems to not work anyways. I'm newbie at JavaScript so possibly will be an easy solution.

```
<script>

function resizeIframe(newHeight) {
      document.getElementById('cursoFrame').style.height = parseInt(newHeight, 10) + 70 + 'px';
  }
</script>



<iframe id="cursoFrame" class="frames" src="http://www.google.es" onload="parent.scroll(0,0);">
```

Comment: You never call `resizeIframe`...

Comment: Seems to be working for me. Only issue will be loading the Google page in an iframe due to cross site scripting issues. I am, of course, assuming you are calling the resizeIframe function at some point after it appears on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the function to work, you need to call it either within the iframe `onload` or within the script.

Currently your script initialises the function, but you are not using it anywhere.

If you add another `script` block below `iframe` block, and type within that script block:

```
<script>
    resizeIframe(400);
</script>
```

This should then call the function and change the height of your iframe.